# Standard Practice Of Placing JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web-inf

**Is it** *valid, standard* and **best practice** to place

- publicly accessible pages be outside the **WEB-INF** folder such as

  > `index.jsp, home.jsp, store.jsp, login.jsp, registration.jsp...`
  >   and
- secured pages like

  > `admin.jsp, reports.jsp, manageusers.jsp, manageproducts.jsp...`

  be inside the **WEB-INF** folder for the *security* reasons(*cannot directly access via url*) by creating **controller servlets** to access them
- and for includes like

  > `navigation.jsp, header.jsp, footer.jsp, sitemap.jsp...`

  be in *specially protected directory* for **not to be** directly access from **url** ??

Comment: and more other suggestions to practice...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a little like someone is having a debate, and wants a tie breaker? :)

This could be sliced a thousand ways... but I personally wouldn't describe the purpose of placing them in WEB-INF for security reasons, it is purely because you do not want the user directly accessing those resources, for a variety of reasons.

It is possible that you could utilize WEB-INF as part of your security infrastructure, but I wouldn't say that is a standard best practice.  Security should start at the request level, and however you deliver those resources to the user is up to you - WEB-INF isn't "the" solution, and it doesn't "need" to be.

Placing accessible resources outside of WEB-INF... well, sure, why not?

Different frameworks might have you place all resources inside WEB-INF somehow, and make them accessible through various controller/filter/serlvet mechanisms, but that would solely be a property of the framework, and shouldn't lead you to believe that placing resources outside of WEB-INF is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you place the JSP pages "outside" of WEB-INF, the Default-Servlet of your Servlet Container (such as Tomcat) will inspect the URL, invoke the JSPs and send back Response to the Browser.
2. When you place then in WEB-INF, then you write your own Servlet (Controller) that inspects the URL and with some sort of logic, forward/redirects to a JSP.

A good security layer (probably based on a Filter) will implement security that will take care of both above cases. Because, do you really want your Default Servlet to be "invoked" by unauthorized folks?

From what I know, the Best Practice is to make a folder called "public" in your "WebContent" folder and put only the unsecure content there. Your Filter should inspect each and ever URL request to your server `/*` and act accordingly.

Also, another Best Practice is never let any URL end with ".jsp". Even something like "welcome" or "login" or "logout" should be handled by your own SecurityFilter + DisplayController

Example:

```
WebContent

--public
----css
------main.css
----images
------logo.png
----js
------common.js
--private  
----js
------ui_handler.js
--WEB-INF
----classes
----jsp
```